# How can you use the types defined in a template in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, types

Given a template class:

```
template<class T, class U>
  struct myList {
    typedef T head;
    typedef U next;
  };

class nullList {};
```

It's possible to make a list of classes, e.g.

```
myList<int, myList<string, myList<short, nullList> > >;
```

I'm trying to use the above list to make a template class that handles only the classes in the list. In the example above, my class would handle ints, strings, and shorts (e.g. printing them to console).

I've been struggling with this for a while, and I'm still not even sure where to start. Any code that begins with

```
template<class T, class U>
class myClass {
    ...
};
```

fails because myClass takes only one template parameter, and that is myList i.e

```
myClass<myList>
```

But if I try to use

```
template<typename l>
class myClass {
   l.head foo;// cannot refer to type member 'head' in 'myList<int, nullList>' with '.'
}
```

Technically myList.head should be a class, right? How can I make use of that information?

Comment: Rename your template as e.g. `mylist` to avoid conflict and confusion with `std::list`. And please read a good [C++ programming](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) book.

Comment: You should explain why you believe that a list template should have two template parameters. I would guess it should have only one (the type of data inside list elements). Or your name `myList` is confusing: you are *not* dealing with any list.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Because it's a list of types, not a list of values. This kind of list template is quite common in template meta programming, which I imagine is what the OP is currently being taught.

Comment: I deleted my answer, and downvoted the question, because I feel it was very confusingly asked!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch As mentioned, the list template was provided to me. I guess the valid classes are passed in as a single-linked list.

Comment: But then, I don't even see why you speak of lists.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Because it's a list of types. `myList<int, myList<string, myList<short, nullList> > >;` is a list containing the types `int`, `string` and `short`. It's not unusual to call that a list - in fact boost's version of this is also called `list` (`boost::mpl::list` to be exact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` operator accesses members of *objects*. `l` is not an object - it's a class. To access static members of classes, you use the `::` operator. When the member you're accessing is a type and the class you're accessing it on is a template parameter, you also need the `typename` keyword for syntactical reasons. So your becomes:

```
template<typename l>
class myClass {
    typename l::head foo;
}
```

If all you want is to print values of the given type and you're not interested in creating objects with members of that type, you could just define a static function that takes the type as its argument:

```
template<typename l>
class myClass {
  public:
    static void print(typename l::head foo) {
        std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    }
};
```

In fact in this case, where you only consider the head of the list, you don't need a class at all and could just do:

```
template<typename l>
void print(typename l::head foo) {
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
}
```

However you'll (probably) need the class once you start taking into account the tail of the list.

Comment: Shouldn't the second occurrence of `typename` be a `typedef` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No. We're declaring a variable, not a typedef. The type of the variable is `l::head` and its name is `foo`.

Comment: But then why not simply use just `l::head foo;` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Because that would lead to a compilation error. As I said "When the member you're accessing is a type and the class you're accessing it on is a template parameter, you also need the typename keyword for syntactical reasons".

Comment: @sepp2k Thank you very much! How would you then use foo? In this case foo would be a class (int), but foo k doesn't syntactically work.

Comment: @PChan You would use `foo` just like you would any other member variable. Usually that means defining public member functions that do something with `foo` and a setter and/or constructor that sets the value of `foo`. What exactly that should be, depends entirely on what you're trying to do (which you didn't really specify beyond saying that you want to "handle" it).

Comment: Notice that this answer is very informative, but does not help the original poster in defining his simple single-linked list template.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch He doesn't want to define a list template - he already has one (which he was given by someone else (his instructor I assume) according to his comments). What he wanted to know was how to access it, which I answered (by using `::` and `typename`).

Comment: @sepp2k Question updated. I'm interested in just printing it out if its type is in the list (e.g. myClass.print( int 3 ); // prints out. myClass.print( float 2.003f ); // fails to compile because float is not in the list)

Comment: @PChan Then you probably don't want a member variable at all, but just define a static function that takes an argument of that type.

Comment: @PChan It means you should define a function that takes an argument of type `typename l::head`.